# How do I make tailwindcss work with the current Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6, tailwind-css

I tried to follow this https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

But since one of the steps requires `ng eject` and as this option is disabled on Angular 6 I am stuck, I tried few options but otherwise found nothing on the web.

Could anyone manage to add tailwindcss to Angular 6?

Thanks

Comment: unfortunately `ng eject` is temporary blocked due to the new `angular.json` format. they recommend using cli version 1.7 if eject is required. (angular-5) https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10618

Comment: can I downgrade to 1.7 and stay with angular 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `npm i ng-tailwindcss`

Read more about it from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-tailwindcss). It's pretty easy to follow it.

If you are setting up a new application, I recommend you do the *'Quick and Dirty Setup'*, it creates the same results as *'Full Installation'*

Comment: @ShaulNaim if you found it useful, please accept as an answer.